# case error while declaring the function now there is error at *from

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
create function whichcountry(@city varchar(20)) returns varchar(30)
as
begin
declare @return varchar(30)
select @return = 
    CASE @city
when 'New delhi' then 'India'
when 'Mumbai' then 'India'
when 'Dhaka' then 'Bangladesh'
else 'UNKNOWN'
end
return @return
end

select country = dbo.whichcountry(city.city),city *from city
create table city(eno int,
                  ename varchar(20),
                  city varchar(30));

insert into city values(1,'Ray','New Delhi'),
                       (2,'Jash','Mumbai'),
                       (3,'Ravi','Dhaka');
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query is product specific.

Comment: '=' is missing, select @return = case when ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected as below (SQL Server)

```
create function whichcountry(@city varchar(20)) returns varchar(30)
as
begin
declare @return varchar(30)
select @return = 
    CASE @city
when 'New delhi' then 'India'
when 'Mumbai' then 'India'
when 'Dhaka' then 'Bangladesh'
else 'UNKNOWN'
end
return @return
end
```

Corrections :

CASE `@city` value was not assigned to `@return`  variable

Comment: invalid object name city after removing *